# Windows Gamebar Record Desktop and not a window

Tags: windows, windows-10, screen-recorder, xbox-game-dvr

I was trying out the windows game bar to record my screen there are two issues that I am not able to figure out.

1. The game bar only records a window and not the desktop. I want the game bar to record my desktop.
2. When a window is being recorded and I minimize the window the recording stops. I want the recording to continue, how can this be achieved?

Comment: Windows GameBar currently doesn’t support recording desktop or any other UWP applications. It is also mentioned in the GameBar settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The game bar only records a window and not the desktop. I want the game bar to record my desktop.

At this time, this is not supported (i.e. it can only record individual applications).

> When a window is being recorded and I minimize the window the recording stops. I want the recording to continue, how can this be achieved?

This [The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2020/4/21/21222533/record-screen-pc-windows-laptop-xbox-game-bar-how-to) article from April 2020 states:

> Open up the application window you want to record. It may help to close or minimize other windows to avoid accidentally recording the wrong one.

This would seem to imply that recording minimized windows is, again, unsupported at this time.